# syscall nice() can't work with negative argument

Tags: linux-kernel, schedule, nice

I try to set my process have negative nice value ex: -20 with syscall `nice(int inc)` or `setpriority(int which, id_t who, int prio)` I check with ps command, it hasn't work even syscall not return an error. Only positive value accepted. With negative value, nice value was set default 0.
Could you help me explain? Thanks

Comment: Has you process privileges to do this? From manpage: Traditionally, only a privileged process could lower the nice value (i.e., set a higher priority).  However, since  Linux  2.6.12, an  unprivileged  process  can  decrease  the nice value of a target process that has a suitable RLIMIT_NICE soft limit; see getrlimit(2) for details.

Comment: Thanks, I will try getrlimit and check RLIMIT_NICE to make sure. Will let you know

Comment: getrlimit return softlimit and hardlimit of my process = 0, I think this is the cause nice() with negative arg not work, to change softlimit and hardlimit need run another process with sudo permission. It was done. My question have ans, thank you.